# What Cisco unity connection messaging system does?

Tags: voiceover, cisco

Today I called a bank of america phone number, but the operator did not pickup the phone.

An automated voice came saying below.

"Welcome to Cisco unity connection messaging system, please spell your last and first names, enter 7 for Q and 9 for z"

I was surprised what to do? Can anyone please explain me what I was supposed to do?

Comment: What aspect of this question is about programming or software development?

Comment: It is to know how a tool works. I did not add any programming language, so I hope it does not fell into those  categories.

Comment: I think you're mistaken about what this place is for.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yes this question is about a software tool only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco Unity is a voicemail system. It was purchased by Cisco from ActiveVoice many years ago. It is telling you to use your telephone's DTMF keyboard to spell names.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/unified-communications/unity-connection/index.html

Comment: I tried that with no help, so got a doubt whether its same or not.